# SQL Server ODBC Driver

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016, odbc

When I create a new ODBC data source, I'm offered 4 different controllers to access SQL Server:

- ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server (Version 2017.140.1000.169)
- SQL Server (Version 10.00.17763.01)
- SQL Server Native Client 11.0 (Version 2011.110.6540.00)
- SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0 (Version 2011.110.5069.66)

What are the differences between them? Which is best/reccomended to connect to an SQL Server instance located in another computer through TCP/IP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440008/differences-between-drivers-for-odbc-drivers

Comment: Couldn't find that question as the title does not include the text "SQL Server".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For new development Microsoft recommends **ODBC Driver for SQL Server**.

Please see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440008
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/connect-history

> There are three distinct generations of Microsoft ODBC drivers for SQL Server. The first "**SQL Server**" ODBC driver still ships as part of Windows Data Access Components. It is not recommended to use this driver for new development. Starting in SQL Server 2005, the **SQL Server Native Client** includes an ODBC interface and is the ODBC driver that shipped with SQL Server 2005 through SQL Server 2012. It is not recommended to use this driver for new development. After SQL Server 2012, the **Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server** is the driver that is updated with the most recent server features going forward.